# How to convert in-memory static array to calldata static array?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, arrays, calldata, solidity-0.8.x

I have a contract called `Erc20Recover` in which I have the following function:

```
pragma solidity >=0.8.0;

contract Erc20Recover {
    function _setNonRecoverableTokens(IErc20[] calldata tokens) public {
        // ...
    }
}
```

I have another contract called `HToken` which inherits from `Erc20Recover` and in whose constructor I attempted to call `_setNonRecoverableTokens`:

```
pragma solidity >=0.8.0;

contract HToken is Erc20Recover {
    constructor(underlying) {
        IErc20[1] memory nonRecoverableTokens = [underlying];
        _setNonRecoverableTokens(nonRecoverableTokens);
    }
}
```

But the code does not compile:

> Invalid type for argument in function call. Invalid implicit conversion from contract IErc20[1] memory to contract IErc20[] calldata requested.

How can I turn that in-memory static array into a calldata array? Or, more generally, how can I call `_setNonRecoverableTokens`?

For context: [IErc20](https://github.com/paulrberg/contracts/blob/c10309f103af1e4bfce6f358844eb8c21f0bd98b/contracts/token/erc20/IErc20.sol) is my implementation of the ERC-20 interface.

Comment: I couldn't figure out how to make the conversion from `memory` to `calldata` but I fixed my problem by defining the `tokens` array as `memory`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not possible to copy data from memory to calldata. Calldata, being the cheapest type of storage, is read-only and can only be used for data passed in to a function through the transaction input.

From the [Solidity documentation](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/latest/introduction-to-smart-contracts.html?highlight=calldata#message-calls):

> As already said, the called contract (which can be the same as the caller) will receive a freshly cleared instance of memory and has access to the call payload - which will be provided in a separate area called the calldata.

As you mentioned in the comments, simply using `memory` instead of `calldata` for `tokens` solves the issue. If you're calling the contract through a transaction, this will simply copy the calldata to the memory.

Comment: Does it cost more gas the way I defined with `memory`?

Comment: It costs slightly gas more to use memory instead of calldata, since the input data needs to be copied to memory.

Answer (score 2):

Besides what [Morten](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/109925/100165) wrote, one can do `this._setNonRecoverableTokens(nonRecoverableTokens);` to call `_setNonRecoverableTokens` *externally* which will copy your memory array to `calldata` (see slide '57' [here](https://takenobu-hs.github.io/downloads/ethereum_evm_illustrated.pdf)). However, calling function externally will also lead to creation of a new context besides incurring previous copy operation, so, calling function `internally` (which happens by simple jumps) is generally more efficient.